# google cloud functions: how to use express.js

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to use express.js in google cloud functions  (NOT firebase).
Express works well, when the the HTTPServer is created via express.

But here, since we just get the "callback," how do I hook ExpressJS and make it work as intended?

Comment: Looking into solving this issue, need to run apollo graphql express serve as a function to reduce deployment cost. Every example/solution is based on firebase. which Express had something like app.execute( req,res)..